# Can I know what changes happened after using native Image Editor?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

If someone uses the WP Image Editor, I want to know what edits were done.

I tried out some simple sample code like this:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_save_image_editor_file', 'after_edit', 10, 5 );


function after_edit( $saved, $filename, $image, $mime_type, $post_id ){
  error_log(print_r($image, true));

  return $saved;
}
```

The output was like this:

```
[08-Nov-2023 21:10:38 UTC] WP_Image_Editor_Imagick Object
(
    [image:protected] => Imagick Object
        (
        )

    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/test.jpg
    [size:protected] => Array
        (
            [width] => 1193
            [height] => 1689
        )

    [mime_type:protected] => image/jpeg
    [output_mime_type:protected] => 
    [default_mime_type:protected] => image/jpeg
    [quality:protected] => 82
    [default_quality:protected] => 82
)
```

As far as I could tell, this is telling me the current state of the image. Not whether it was rotated vs scaled vs cropped. Is there no way to know that?